# web project not functioning correctly in Visual Studio live server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html/css/javascript files in a Visual Studio folder. I am trying to change my div element with id = "top" to "Text change" instead of "top". As you can see, it is functioning correctly in the code snippet, but when I run my html file with the live server extension in Visual Studio, the javascript fails to make a change. I believe I am linking my css and javascript correctly to my html file. What is wrong here?

```js
document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = "Text change";
```

```css
#top {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}

#middle {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 500px;
}

#bottom {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="javascript-test.js"></script>

  <div id="top">top</div>
  <div id="middle">middle</div>
  <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just a quick test - Try moving your `scrip` tag after the `div` elements. Your `javascript` might be executing too early.

Comment: That did it... thought it might be an easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript is running before your HTML loads. Move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of your page, just before your closing `</body>` tag:

```
  <script src="javascript-test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `<script>`tag in the `<head>` to make the javascript run first.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="javascript-test.js"></script>
</head>
```